# EntityFramework doesn't update database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, entity-framework

I have a problem with updating data base through entity frame work.

My XAML code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="0,5,0,0"
           DataContext="{StaticResource directoryViewSource}">
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=id}"
                          Width="50"
                          CanUserResize="True"
                          IsReadOnly="True" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="*" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sername"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=sername, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="*" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=address, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="*" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=email, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="*" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modified_by"
                          Binding="{Binding Path=users.user_name}"
                          Width="*"
                          IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

And c# code:

```
        WpfApplication1.db_test_directoryEntities1 db_test_directoryEntities1;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.db_test_directoryEntities1 = new WpfApplication1.db_test_directoryEntities1();
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource directoryViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("directoryViewSource")));
            System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication1.directory> directoryQuery = this.db_test_directoryEntities1.directory;
            directoryViewSource.Source = directoryQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
        }

        private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.db_test_directoryEntities1.SaveChanges();
        }
```

So.. Datacontext updates but the database is not. Database (.mdf1) was create when I was creating entity Model.
What do you think? Why database doesn't update

if I put a breakpoint on SaveChanges() then I can see how setting stopped on ReportPropertyChanged("name"); and the method OnnameChanged(); doesn't use

```
public global::System.String name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                OnnameChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("name");
                _name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("name");
                OnnameChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try setting your Bindings to `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: have you put a breakpoint in debug mode on SaveChanges() ?

Comment: Mode=TwoWay have set.
Yes, when I put a breakpoint on this line I can seeing how my changes have saved in entity model

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in DataGrid_RowEditEnding can you look at the item to confirm that the state of the object is edited?

Comment: I have little changed question

Comment: Try adding "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" on your bindings. `Binding="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}"` would become `Binding="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RowEdidEnding is fired just before committing the modified row. Maybe you are saving before the changes are committed to the bound object.

A (not very clean) solution might be:

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         new Action(()=>this.db_test_directoryEntities1.SaveChanges()), 
         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```